# Xamarin sample project missing dependencies, but files are present

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, target

I have been trying to build and run the ACR Reactive Bluetooth LE sample projects (found here: https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle) in Visual Studio using Xamarin. However, I get the error:

---

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       The specified language targets for uap10.0.16299 is missing. Ensure correct tooling is installed for 'uap'. Missing: 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsXaml\v16.0\Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.CSharp.targets'    Plugin.BluetoothLE  C:\Users\Renow.nuget\packages\msbuild.sdk.extras\2.0.29\Build\LanguageTargets\CheckMissing.targets 36

---

for each of the targets I am trying to target; macOS, iOS, Android, and UAP. I have located each of the files VS is searching for in the specified path, but VS just can't seem to find them. The dependencies for the project I am trying to build are also showing the yellow warning triangle.

I have attempted to restore my Nuget packages, clear the Nuget cache and restore, reinstalling VS, and manually installing the packages I am using to no avail.

Comment: Hi, if you re-isntall the nuget package, it always can not work?

Comment: Reinstalling the Nuget packages does not work, nor does reinstalling Nuget all together

Comment: @ReedNowling,did you follow [the guidance of the the github link](https://github.com/aritchie/bluetoothle#setup)? You should install that nuget package `Plugin.BluetoothLE`.